# Highlight multiple dates on jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui-datepicker

If I try to highlight dates on jquery datepicker by providing it a static array. It works absolutely fine. If I generate the array inside a loop and then provide it. There is no way that I found to get the dates highlighted. Code is below.

```
  // var tempDates=["2015/01/07","2015/01/14","2015/01/21"];
                var tempDates = []; tempDates=datesToHighlight;


                line.datepicker({disabled:false, defaultDate: dateObj, dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
                    beforeShowDay: function (highlightMe) {
                        var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', highlightMe);
                        var highlightIndex = $.inArray(dateString.toString(), tempDates);
                        if(highlightIndex>-1) {
                            return [true, 'highlight', tips[highlightIndex]];
                        }
                        var aIndex = $.inArray(dateString, selected);
                        return [aIndex == -1]
                    }
                });
```

This is the format in which dates are generated by the loop.

```
 2015/01/07
 2015/01/14
 2015/01/21
 2015/01/28
 2015/02/04
 2015/02/11
 2015/02/18
```

Loop that I used to generate the array.

```
for (var k = 0; k < selectedArrayLength; k++) {
                    if (new Date(selected[k]).getMonth() == monthIndex[ind%12]) {

                        var dateFormat = new Date(selected.splice(k, 1));
                        var curr_date = addZ(dateFormat.getDate());
                        var curr_month = dateFormat.getMonth();
                        curr_month++;
                        var curr_year = dateFormat.getFullYear();
                        var newFormat = (curr_year + "/" + addZ(curr_month) + "/" + curr_date);
                        thisMonthDates.push(newFormat);
                        //thisMonthDates.push(selected.splice(k, 1));
                        k--; // since we removed an element we need to decrement k
                    }
                }


  for(var eachDt=0; eachDt<thisMonthDates.length; eachDt++) {
                    console.log(thisMonthDates[eachDt]);
                    var datesToHighlight = new Array();
                    datesToHighlight.push(new Date(thisMonthDates[eachDt]));

                }
```

**Log of the code.**

```
Year Difference: 2 end year: 2015 start year: 2015
78 Difference of days.
 12 : Selected Array Length 
 calendar0
 4
 2015/01/07
 2015/01/14
 2015/01/21
 2015/01/28
 4
 ["2015/01/07", "2015/01/14", "2015/01/21", "2015/01/28"]
 calendar1
 4
 2015/02/04
 2015/02/11
 2015/02/18
 2015/02/25
 4
 ["2015/02/04", "2015/02/11", "2015/02/18", "2015/02/25"]
 calendar2
 4
 2015/03/04
 2015/03/11
 2015/03/18
 2015/03/25
 4
 ["2015/03/04", "2015/03/11", "2015/03/18", "2015/03/25"]
 SELECTED ARRAY IS EMPTY.
 0,1,2 - 2015,2015,2015
```

Comment: is `datesToHighlight` another array or is it a function?

Comment: really not clear what specific issue is. A demo might help along with better explanation of problem

Comment: @mikelt21 its an array.

Comment: @mikelt21 `datesToHighlight` is generated inside a loop. Then I refer it to tempDates. But it is not working don't get any idea :(

Comment: Not sure if datepicker supports multiple date highlighting since its set with defaultDate to begin with. I know fullcalendar... http://fullcalendar.io/ does

Comment: @zgr024 it does. I'm sure and it works fine with the static array as I commented above.

Comment: @Superman then its obviously your loop where the dates are being set in datesToHighlight. Can you post that?

Comment: Where is thisMonthDates being set? It helps if you include all of your code that is relevant

Comment: your `datesToHighlight` array is an array of Date objects, whereas your hardcoded array of days is an array of strings

Comment: @zgr024 then it looks too messy and no one willing to answer. Yes there are many who are always ready to down vote. And they did it twice before. That's why not pasting full code here.

Comment: @mikelt21... thats just for starters... he is also resetting the array inside the loop with `var datesToHighlight = new Array();` so you will only end up with 1 date object anyway but of course its not a string either

Comment: @zgr024 this highlight code runs under a while loop. Which I used to run this code once for each instance of the calendar. Also pasting the monthArray code.

Comment: but you are resetting the array inside the for loop... which will only give you 1 date object in the end. Besides the fact that a Date object is not a string in the format you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your `for` loop for creating `datesToHighlight`. You don't need to create a date object for each `thisMonthDates` item and you were recreating a new array for each day so I moved your `datesToHighlight` initialization outside the loop.

```
var datesToHighlight = [];
for(var eachDt=0; eachDt<thisMonthDates.length; eachDt++) {
    console.log(thisMonthDates[eachDt]);
    datesToHighlight.push(thisMonthDates[eachDt]);
}
```

Comment: No success. I think that by wrapping each element inside quotes might help. As static array that we provide this code works fine. And its each element has quotes. How I can wrap each element inside quotes?

Comment: No that quote thing doesn't helped.

Comment: that just means that your dates are actually strings and not Date objects. I'm trying to populate `datesToHighlight` as an array of strings.

Comment: can you post a printout of your `thisMonthDates` array after it's generated? also why are you using `splice` in `selected.splice(k, 1)`? why don't you just use `selected[k]`? then you won't need to do `k--` at the end of the loop. this could cause issues too.

Comment: If I don't use splice then iterations will always be remain same. Because I'm splicing the original array which contains all the selected dates in it.

Comment: you have it in a for loop. k will increment every loop.

Comment: k is just to iterate over all the selected dates and used in the date format loop only. you can see it above.

Comment: Main loop is the while loop and it driven by the value of `ind`. ind is an index for each month. So it also holds and make sure the id of the calendar instance. It is just to make sure that each calendar for every month.

Comment: it's so hard to debug your code because everything is dependent on everything else. and there are so many variables everywhere. is there any way you can just email me your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68360/discussion-between-mikelt21-and-superman).